# Shell script input

Tags: unix, shell

```
#!/bin/sh 

if test -n $1  
then  
  echo "Some input entered"  
  echo $1  
else  
  echo "no input entered"  
fi
```

The above code is supposed to say "no input entered" if I dont pass an argument to the shell script. the echo $1 shows a blank line when I dont pass any arguments. 
its saying "some input entered" even without any arguments.

Comment: [-n string] True if the string is not null

Comment: Are you deliberately trying to maintain bourne shell compatibility? Can't you use `#!/bin/bash`? And finally, if you're using bash, forget `test` and start using `if [[ cond ]] ; then` form of syntax. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip `test` and put quotes around the `$1`:

```
#!/bin/sh 

if [ -n "$1" ]
then  
  echo "Some input entered"  
  echo $1  
else  
  echo "no input entered"  
fi
```

Comment: `[` is just a synonym for `test`

Comment: @evil otto - I did not know that, but now that I look at the `test` manpage, I see that you are correct! :)  @dasman should give you the check, as you had the answer first.

Answer (score 5):

put quotes around your `$1`.  Without them, the $1 just vanishes and `test` confusingly reports "nothing" to be not empty.

```
if test -n "$1" 
then
    ....
```